# Zoomcharts right click node disable glow/shadow

Tags: zoomcharts

I am using the zoomcharts net chart, and I am having issues disabling the glow you get when you right click a node. Ive looked at the api over and over and do not see an option for doing this. The closest ive gotten was handling the right click event.

Using event.preventDefault() I have successfully disabled the menu that pops up when you right click, but that is as far as ive gotten. The glow still shows.

If anyone can point me to an example or provide any input I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of highlights: hover glow and selection.
The hover glow is defined in settings.style.nodeHovered.
The selection glow is defined in settings.style.selection.

On right click the node is selected. So adding this to your settings should fix things:

```
style:{
    selection: {
        fillColor: "transparent"
    }
}
```